# Dart enters one area, but tip enters another

Tags: rules, darts

[image: Example]

In the picture, the dart enters through the single 19 area, but the tip goes under the metal separator and sticks in the double 19. What is the correct way to score this?

Answer (score 2):

The current rules of darts, as established by the Darts Regulation Authority, can be found [here](http://www.thedra.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DRA2019Rules_110119-final-1.pdf). The PDC refers to them on their [Rules of Darts](https://www.pdc.tv/players/rules-darts) page. The rules state the following:

> 5.4.2 A scoring dart is counted by reference to the segment into which the point of the dart enters and remains in or touching the face of the dartboard.

Now, what is a segment? There's no explicit definition, but the following rule suggest they'd never expect a situation like in the question to happen:

> 5.5.7 All the wires forming the doubles and trebles segments, inner and outer centre rings which together form the “Spider”, shall be affixed to the face of the dartboard in such a manner that they lie flat on the face of the dartboard and feature no gaps or splits.

I'd argue that the dart is in the double 19 segment (its tip is fully in the green zone) so it counts as a double.

---

Now what would happen if it's exactly on the white/green border? There's always a catch-all rule:

> 5.4.8 The Referee shall act as an umpire in all matters pertaining to these General Playing Rules when conducting a Darts Event and shall, if it is necessary, consult with Scorers and other Officials before announcing any decisions during the course of Match play.

Or perhaps more explicitly:

> 5.3.9 The Referee will have the final say in all matters relating to starting and finishing.

though this may happen during the 'scoring' phase of a game as well.

Comment: I don't know anything about darts, but based on 5.5.7, if this situation is never supposed to happen, then maybe the board itself should be considered defective, and the rules about broken or bad boards should apply. IMHO the fairer solution from the point of view of all contestants is to replace the board and redo the shot.

Comment: Good quotes, but I believe the wrong conclusion. That dart, as per OP's wording "enters through the single 19 area", and is therefore a single 19.

Answer (score 2):

You score based on the wire-defined segment, not where the tip is.   In the photo, that dart scores single 19.

The wires are there specifically to avoid any ambiguity about the location where the point touches.

From 2024 [DRA Rules](https://www.thedra.co.uk/_files/ugd/20bb2f_3cf54f94fda34811a90f4e87ed72cf76.pdf), the first two scoring rules refer only to scoring based on the wires and rings, not any other criteria (such as location of the tip).

> 6.4.1 A dart shall only score if the point of the dart remains in or touches the face of
> the dartboard **within the outer double wire** and, having been “called”, is
> retrieved from the face of the dartboard by the Player throwing that dart.

> 6.4.2 A scoring dart is counted **by reference to the segment into which the point of**
> the dart enters and remains in or touching the face of the dartboard.

The tip of the dart must remain in contact with the board to score (it can't be "hanging" on the wire with the tip clear of the board).  But the location of the tip on the board is not relevant.  Only the segment that is entered determines the scoring.